# how to push view.xib on UILocalNotification receive when Root view controller is Tab bar controller?

Tags: ios, iphone

I am trying to push the View.xib when the my UILocalNotification receives in my Appdelegate.m file. but my main root view controller is tab bar controller.

**my code is not working which is as below:**

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{

    application.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0;  
    UILocalNotification *localNotif = [launchOptionsobjectForKey:UIApplicationLaunchOptionsLocalNotificationKey];
    if (localNotif)  
    {  
        NSLog(@"Recieved Notification %@\n",localNotif);  
    }  
    _window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];  
    _tabBarController = [[AKTabBarController alloc] initWithTabBarHeight:            (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) ? 70 : 50];

    [_tabBarController setViewControllers:[NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:
                                           navigationController,
                                           navigationController2,
                                           navigationController3,
                                           nil]];  
    [_window setRootViewController:_tabBarController];  
    [_window makeKeyAndVisible];  
    return YES;  
}  


-(void)application:(UIApplication *)application
     didReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notification     
{    
    NSLog(@"in didReceiveLocalNotification");    
    StartViewController2Track *viewController = [[StartViewController2Track    alloc]initWithNibName:NSStringFromClass([StartVie Controller2Track class]) bundle:nil];    

 //   [self.window.rootViewController presentViewController:viewController animated:YES completion:nil ];    

//    [self.navcontrol pushViewController:viewController animated:YES];

    [self.rootViewController.tabBarController.selectedViewController.navigationController [pushViewController:StartViewController2Track animated]];    

}
```

Comment: Do You want to display `UIView` when your LocalNotif. is arrive??

Comment: you're reaching down the stack very far to push that view controller.  In debug, I would verify that all those properties you're reaching into are not nil.  That may help guide you down the path of pushing it via the right navigationController

Comment: @iPatel: yes And my in my Window root i am adding Tab controller in AppDelegate.m

Comment: If you want to display UIView then you also can be add as subView of window :)

Comment: @Patel Let me Try It and give response to you for That,thanks.

Comment: @Patel Its not working....i am just nevigated to my first tab conroller..!

Answer (score 0):

Your rootviewcontroller is tabbarController. So you are trying to push from `tabbarcontroller.tabbarcontroller` and also selectedViewcontroller is also navigation controller. sot Try below..

```
[self.window.rootViewController.selectedViewController pushViewController:viewController animated:YES]];
```

Comment: it gives me error:   Property "rootViewController" not found on Object of Type 'App Delegate *'